View php file path under footer
I am in the process of building a new site. On my old site, when logged in, I was able to view the path for each PHP file that ran a page. Any clue why i cant see this on new site?


Different site would mean different themes and plugins, so likely that's it. A plugin like Query Monitor will show you the template file, as well as a lot of other helpful pieces of information.

that would make the most sense, but there is no plug in.

Then it's likely in the theme.

it only shows when i am signed in. ugh. i may just have to get a plug in. thx

It's not difficult to do, but that's not your question.

not difficult as in adding a plug in, or do you know of a differnt solution?

There are multiple ways of accomplishing adding that, but using Query Monitor is the best imo.
